# Dictionary: Find same value using different but identical instances as keys

Tags: c#, dictionary

Is it possible to achive the following behaviour from a dictionary in a convenient way:

```
Dictionary<MyObject, double> d = new Dictionary<MyObject, double>
MyObject foo = new MyObject("foo");
d[foo] = 1.0;

Console.Write(d[new MyObject("foo")]) ---> 1.0
```

The example is simplified, I am using a slightly more complex Object as key.

Edit replaced String with MyObject

Comment: I dont get it, different but identical instances? Your code works as expcted. It prints `1`.

Comment: with `string` it will work correctly ("out of the box")... With other object types, you have to override `GetHashCode` and `Equals`

Comment: It is to different strings, but identical contents. new MyObject() == new MyObject() --> False

Comment: usually you do `if (!d.ContainsKey(foo)) { d.Add(foo, 0) } d[foo] = 1.0;`

Comment: @CallumLinington: Why? OP's approach is more efficient.

Comment: What happens in the OPs approach if a key already exists?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible, as long as the corresponding `Equals()` method of your key returns `true`, and `GetHashCode()` returns the same integer value for what you call `different but identical instances`.

In your example the result is 1.0 because `String.Equals` compares contents of the strings, not references (although, to be precise, references in your example will most probably be the same as well, because the compiler usually pools identical strings).
EDIT: this paragraph applied to the original question, where the OP used `string` as the key.

If you use custom class for keys, just override its `Equals` method to achieve desired behavior. Don't forget to override `GetHashCode()` as well for efficient dictionary lookup, see this for reasoning: [Why is it important to override GetHashCode when Equals method is overridden?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/371328/why-is-it-important-to-override-gethashcode-when-equals-method-is-overridden)

Comment: Thank you, I must have made an error in my GetHashCode implementation. I'll do some testing :)

Comment: Always override `Equals` **and** `GetHashCode`. You can also implement an `IEquatable<MyObject>` or an `IEqualityComparer<MyObject>`. The former works implicitly, the latter by using [this dictionary constructor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132072(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: @Tim Schmelter, good point, re-phrased my answer to include your recommendation